# Creating points with z value with Python in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, xyz

I am a beginner in Python, and I would like to create points (and entities) with a Z value (x,y,z) in QGIS.

I found this code, in order to create 4 points, but it is only (x,y) entities. I need to set a Z value for each point, if it's possible.

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=EPSG:4326', 'point', 'memory') 
provider = layer.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('Name', QVariant.String)])
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('ID', QVariant.Int)])
layer.updateFields() 
f = QgsFeature()
p1 = QgsPointXY(78.25, 14.25)
p2 = QgsPointXY(78.25, 14.50)
p3 = QgsPointXY(78.50, 14.50)
p4 = QgsPointXY(78.50, 14.25)
f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(p1))
f.setAttributes(['Lower Left',1])
provider.addFeature(f)
f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(p2))
f.setAttributes(['Upper Left',2])
provider.addFeature(f)
f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(p3))
f.setAttributes(['Upper Right',3])
provider.addFeature(f)
f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(p4))
f.setAttributes(['Lower Right',4])
provider.addFeature(f)
layer.updateExtents() 
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, "C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/Articles PEM/Graphiques/testpoint11.shp", "UTF-8", layer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")
path = "C:/XXX/XXX/Desktop/Articles PEM/Graphiques"
layerfile = QgsVectorLayer(path, "test point", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layerfile)
```

Do you have any idea ?

EDIT : I changed my code using QgsPoint (x, y, z) but it doesn't work :

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=EPSG:4326', 'point', 'memory') 
provider = layer.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('Name', QVariant.String)])
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('ID', QVariant.Int)])
layer.updateFields() 
f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(QgsPoint(78.25, 14.25, 500))
f.setAttributes(['Lower Left',1])
provider.addFeature(f)
f.setGeometry(QgsPoint(78.25, 14.50, 400))
f.setAttributes(['Upper Left',2])
provider.addFeature(f)
f.setGeometry(QgsPoint(78.50, 14.50, 600))
f.setAttributes(['Upper Right',3])
provider.addFeature(f)
f.setGeometry(QgsPoint(78.50, 14.25, 400))
f.setAttributes(['Lower Right',4])
provider.addFeature(f)
layer.updateExtents() 
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, "C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/Articles PEM/Graphiques/testpoint11.shp", "UTF-8", layer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")
path = "C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/Articles PEM/Graphiques"
layerfile = QgsVectorLayer(path, "test point", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layerfile)
```

Is it the good way ?

[image]

Comment: See [Creating 3D points in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250397/creating-3d-points-in-pyqgis)

Comment: I checked the post but I am too beginner to understand what I have to modify. I tried to put my Z values directly in the code but it didn't work... Could someone help me ?

Comment: Use `QgsPoint` instead of `QgsGeometry.fromPointXY()`. If you're creating features (like in the code snippet you posted), you can set their geometry in this way: `feature.setGeometry(QgsPoint(-74, 4, 2600))`, where `2600` is the `z` value.

Comment: I changed my code by this one but it doesn't work. The Z value is not created. Is it good ?
f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(QgsPoint(78.25, 14.25, 500))
f.setAttributes(['Lower Left',1])

Comment: That's correct. Just make sure you save changes in your layer, which your code snippet doesn't seem to be doing properly. See how to do it in [the docs](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#add-features). You can run `print(feature.z())` to verify z is being set.

Comment: My points are well saved in my folder, I can see them in Qgis, but the Z value is not implemented, again. I can't run the print command because I have an issue. I am a bit desperated... Thanks again !! @GermánCarrillo

Comment: I forgot to specifiy the Pointz : layer = QgsVectorLayer('Pointz?crs=EPSG:4326', 'point', 'memory'), and now it works. Thanks !